# how to add this condition in table?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

i want to create a table which store `USERNAME` and `DOMAIN`(both are col. name of same table). 
One User can only belong to one domain.

and the The Domain values can be stored in the another table, lets call it "LIST".

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: i want to create a table which will have 2 col. named as  USERNAME and DOMAIN

Comment: and One User can only belong to one and only one domain. i don't know who to add this condition(check)                                                                             and the The Domain values can be stored in the another table lets say it "LIST".

Comment: Yeah, but what is the problem? you don't know how to create the table, you don't know how to create the foreign key to the other table?

Comment: don't know how to add condition One User can only belong to one and only one domain. i don't know who to add this condition(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set in your `users` table `domain_id` (as relation with domain), then use constraints for two columns (`username` and `domain_id`).

MySql example:
`ALTER TABLE users ADD UNIQUE unique_index (username, domain_id);`

P.S. Look for analog in SQL server. (see example in comments)

Comment: @D.Dimitrioglo, why mention MySql? He is using SQL Server. The answer is valid though.

Comment: I think that most of relational db have almoust similar sinax

Comment: `ADD UNIQUE` is MySql syntax, for Sql server it's `ADD CONSTRAINT <constraint name> UNIQUE (<columns>)`

Comment: Thanks, I've added some P.S. in my answer

Comment: could u tell in sql server syntax !! @D.Dimitrioglo

Comment: ALTER TABLE users  ADD CONSTRAINT UC_username_domain_id UNIQUE( username, domain_id );

Comment: OP asked for ONE USER in ONE DOMAIN, this constraint allow ONE user on MANY domains

Answer (score 1):

I suggest this kind of script to create your tables and put on them determined conditions:

```
--Create table that will store domains
CREATE TABLE DICT_DOMAINS (
    DomainID int IDENTITY(1,1),
    DomainName nvarchar(255),
CONSTRAINT [PK_DICT_DOMAINS] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (DomainID ASC)
)
--DomainNames must be unique so we add non clustered index
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [UX_DICT_DOMAINS_DomainName] ON DICT_DOMAINS (DomainName ASC)
--Create table to store users and there domains
CREATE TABLE USERS_DOMAINS (
    DomainID int,
    UserName nvarchar(255)
)
--Add foreign key to DICT_DOMAINS table
ALTER TABLE USERS_DOMAINS WITH CHECK ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_USERS_DOMAINS_DICT_DOMAINS] FOREIGN KEY (DomainID)
REFERENCES DICT_DOMAINS (DomainID)

--Usernames must be uniq, no need to add DomainsId to this index
--This is sufficient to provide condition that
--One User can only belong to one domain.
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [UX_USERS_DOMAINS_UserName] ON USERS_DOMAINS (UserName ASC)
```